# C#, SQL Server database, connection timeout. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool

Tags: sql-server, connection, connection-timeout

I am using a connection class for my connection and then I call the class for connecting.

After I use the connection several times it freezes and then gives a error. It seems I have got to many connections open at the same time I can't figure out how tho close the open connections. If that is the real  problem.

`MyConnection` class:

```
 public class MyConnection
 {
     private SqlConnection _con;
     public SqlCommand Cmd;
     private SqlDataAdapter _da;
     private DataTable _dt;

     public MyConnection()
     {
        _con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.1.12\\grs;Initial Catalog=BGI;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=awplanung;Password=pass");

        _con.Open();
     }

     public void SqlQuery(string queryText)
     {
         Cmd = new SqlCommand(queryText, _con);
     }

     public DataTable QueryEx()
     {
         _da = new SqlDataAdapter(Cmd);
         _dt = new DataTable();
         _da.Fill(_dt);
         return _dt;
     }

     public void NonQueryEx()
     {
         Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
}
```

And now I call this connection from my forms: like this one.

```
MyConnection con = new MyConnection();

con.SqlQuery("SELECT ARartikelnr ,ARartikelbezeich, ARartwarengruppe,  ARanzahleinheiten, ARinhalteinheiten, ARanzgebindepal FROM BGARTIKEL where ARartikelnr BETWEEN '" + textBox2.Text + "' and '" + textBox3.Text + "' order by ARinhalteinheiten, ARartwarengruppe");

dt = con.QueryEx();
```

Each time I open a new form I make a

```
MyConnection con = new MyConnection();
```

and make many similar

```
con.SqlQuery("Select string")
```

After I open a second form it freezes when I do a new long select. What is strange is that I have used these 2 forms without problems, but in the first one I made a datagrid fill with a button. and now i changed if to fill directly from the form load. and when i go to the next form i cant fill my other datagrid on the new form giving that error.

Error:

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

Comment: You should be creating a connection, using it, then disposing it.  You're probably not.  Stop not disposing of your connections when done with them.

Comment: And now that you know how to solve the problem at hand you need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. What you have posted is a text book example of exactly how NOT to create a query. You should NEVER directly execute text received from an end user.

Answer (score 2):

Make your MyConnection class disposable. And dispose it when you are done with data.

1. implement IDisposable interface on class

> (public class MyConnection : IDisposable)

2. implement Dispose method where dispose your connection

> public void Dispose()
>       {
>       _con.Dispose();
>       }

3. and use it like this

> using(MyConnection con = new MyConnection())
>       {
>           con.SqlQuery("...");
>           dt = con.QueryEx();
>       }

Comment: Thanks! that worked like a charm!! A appreciate your clear answer!

Comment: Mark it as answer if it really helped. Thanks.